# Selendroid - How to capture logcat

Tags: logcat, capture, selendroid

I have a need to capture and parse information that is written to the logcat for the app that I am testing with Selendroid. I want capture the request response pairs that are sent to the web service that my mobile app uses. My mobile app records the request that is sent, the http response code and the response that is received. Is there any mechanism in Selendroid to do capture the logcat information? Is there any way that I could add this capability to the existing 0.12.0 codebase that I am using? I do know that using the code below will dump the logcat to the Selendroid output console.

```
AdbConnection adbConn = driver.getAdbConnection();
adbConn.executeShellCommand("logcat");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running this as an adb command seperately. Start an adb shell and type:

```
logcat -f <location to place the log output>
```

When done you can pull the log file using an adb `PULL` command.